# avoid cookies to be sent to sub domain

Tags: javascript, cookies, subdomain

How to avoid cookies to be sent to sub domain 
Using below script

> ```
> function createCookie(name,value,days){
>   if (days) {
>       var date = new Date();
>       date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
>       var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
>   }
>   else var expires = "";
>   document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below script worked for me

```
    document.cookie = cookieName +"=" + cookieValue + ";expires=" 
+ myDate + ";domain=www.abc.com;path=/";
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just check the domain thats calling the script first and then only set the cookie if it's not a sub domain?

Something like:

```
if (Request.Host.toLower() == "www.abc.com"){
    createCookie(name,day,values);
 }
```

Comment: your welcome. Please mark it as answered if it worked, helps future visitors with similar issues :)

Comment: I think correct solution is document.cookie = cookieName +"=" + cookieValue + ";expires=" + myDate + ";domain=www.abc.com;path=/";